# List index out of bounds, what's the problem please?

Tags: apex

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="Recherche_Contact" >

    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >         
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Recherche Contact" columns="2" id="IdSection" >
             Nom: <apex:inputField id="name" value="{!currcontact.FirstName}" /><br />
             Prénom: <apex:inputField id="prenom" value="{!currcontact.LastName}" /><br />
             Email: <apex:inputField id="email" value="{!currcontact.Email}" />
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
         <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Chercher" /> 
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" /> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And i have the controller

```
public class Recherche_Contact {    

    public String IdContact{get;set;} // 
    public Contact currcontact{get;set;} 
    public List <Contact> lstContact{get;set;}
    public USER currUser{get;set;}

   public Recherche_Contact(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        IdContact = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('IdContact'); 
        initialisationGenerale(); 
        currcontact= lstContact[0];
    }
}
```

I have the error: List index out of bounds: 0 !!!!

Comment: your field `lstContact` has never instantiated. To get the first item as you are trying, you have to populate it with some `Contact` records. Check on that

Comment: What's the content of `initialisationGenerale()`?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the list that you are trying to access is initialized (maybe in **initialisationGenerale()** method) however it is empty and you are trying to access 1st record from that list.

I belive you are getting the error in this line
`currcontact= lstContact[0];`

Please add a `System.debug(lstContact);` before `currcontact= lstContact[0];`. to check.